# zsh completion for kill listing unexpected "0"

Tags: zsh, ps, rc

I have following in my `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*' command 'ps -u $USER -o pid,%cpu,tty,cputime,cmd'
```

When I press TAB, in addition to processes being listed, there is always a last line containing the digit `0`.

why is that? Can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
```

And try again, you'll see:

> ```
> Completing process-group
> ```

Just above that `0`. `kill 0` does kill the current process group. See https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00713.html for the rationale, though I'll have to admit neither their explanation nor the code in the diff there makes much sense to me.

You can make it go away with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*:process-groups' hidden true
```

Or:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*:process-groups' hidden all
```

to also make the *`Completing process-group`* header go away (see `info zsh hidden` for details).

Comment: how can I get rid of this feature? I don't need to kill process groups, and it is just bothering me.

Comment: @400theCat, I have to admit little of that makes any sense to me. You can  always create your own copy of `_kill` with that patch reverted. I'll bring it up on the mailing list to see if anyone can make sense out of it.

Comment: @400theCat, see edit about how to make that 0 go away.